# Pages not loading within Password Protected Directory

Tags: .htaccess

I have password protected a directory called 'admin' using the usual .htaccess method:

```
AuthType Basic  
AuthName "restricted area"  
AuthUserFile xx.xxx.xxx.xx/public_html/admin/.htpasswd  
require valid-user
```

When I load the home page of the site which is password protected, I log in and home page loads fine, but then when I click a link to load a sub-page, the home page just reloads. There are links which open pop-ups and these pop-ups are also containing the home page when they should be loading forms etc..

Is there something missing in my .htaccess file?

Comment: Is that all you have in your .htaccess file? Any other .htaccess files? What is the URL you are requesting? Is it "redirecting" back to the homepage? Or do you see the correct URL in the address bar?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the correct URL is in the address bar but the content is the home page. I have a Wordpress install in the root with its usual htaccess but this admin directory is created from a subdomain so is (or should not be) affected by the Wordpress htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a Wordpress install in the root with its usual htaccess but this admin directory is created from a subdomain so is (or should not be) affected by the Wordpress htaccess.

If this subdomain is pointing to a subdirectory off the main domain's document root (which is what it looks like) then the parent directory's "WordPress" .htaccess *will* affect this. .htaccess files are inherited along the *filesystem* path.

Since WordPress uses mod_rewrite you can prevent mod_rewrite from being inherited by simply enabling the rewrite engine in the subdomains .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

AuthType Basic
# etc...
```

Other modules will still be inherited, although the default WordPress install does not use any other modules.

---

Alternatively you can try adding an exception to the parent directory's .htaccess file, in order to exclude it being processed when accessing the subdomain (or rather *only* process it when accessing via the main-domain). Add the following to the top of the WordPress .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=example.com
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Where `example.com` is your main-domain. Which basically says if the host is not the main-domain then abort.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have put RewriteEngine On in to the subdomains .htaccess before the Auth stuff and this made the page inaccessable and I got an Internal Server Error.

Comment: Do you mean an error log within cpanel? The error log in the directory doesn't say anything as it's not a PHP error.

Comment: Your server's error log. If you get a 500 Internal Server Error, the server's error log should give you more details as to the specific error. My _guess_ is that mod_rewrite is not enabled (or _permitted_) for your subdomain / directory path? But the error log would confirm this. How is your subdomain defined?

Comment: I've checked the error log in the cpanel and also the raw access log but it does nto have any entries for the time when I got the internal server error.

Comment: Alternatively you can try adding an exception to the parent (WordPress) .htaccess file. I've updated my answer.

Comment: sorry @w3d but this also generated the same internal server error as the previous answer.